# Vagrant: Port forwarding not working (no service iptables started, provisioned by salt)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, portforwarding, salt-stack

This is my Vagrantfile.

> VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
>
> Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
>
> config.vm.box = "precise32"
>   config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
>
> config.vm.hostname = "myapp.dev"
>
> config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000, auto_correct: true
>
> config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8983, host: 8983, auto_correct: true
>
> config.vm.synced_folder "salt/roots/", "/srv/"
>    config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
>
> ```
> salt.minion_config = "salt/minion"                                         
> salt.run_highstate = true                                                  
> salt.install-type = "daily"                                                
> salt.verbose = true
> ```
>
> end
>   config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
>
> ```
> v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
> ```
>
> end
>
> end

From inside the vagrant machine, `curl -L localhost:9000|wc` returns a lot of words, lines and whatnot, and the answer is a HTTP proper response.

From outside the vagrant machine, `curl -L localhost:9000|wc` returns 0 lines (and the others), and `curl -L localhost:9000` returns the message `Connection reset by peer`.

The service iptables is running neither in my local machine, nor in my virtual machine.

the services that are running in my virtual vagrant machine are

- [ + ]  apache2
- [ + ]  apparmor
- [ + ]  memcached
- [ + ]  ntp
- [ + ]  rabbitmq-server
- [ + ]  ssh
- [ + ]  supervisor
  (i've only listed the ones with '+' status)

The services running on my local machine are

- [ + ]  apparmor
- [ + ]  redis-server
- [ + ]  saned

If any more info is required, i'll supply it.

**[EDIT]**
I've also tried netcat-ing

on the virtual machine:

> $ nc -l 8978

on the local machine

```
>$ nc localhost 8978
>$
```

At this point the connection initiated from the local machine to the virtual machine is closed, but the virtual machine keeps listening)

**HOWEVER**, when i start listening with `nc -l 65530` on the local machine, and connect to it with `nc 65530`, i **can** send packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

VirtualBox was caussing the issue:

Apparently i had another box started up, which was also listening on port 9000. When i started up my box, i received a message that instead of forwarding from 9000 -> 9000, it was forwarding from 2201 -> 9000. I simply turned off the other box.

This was happening because of the `auto_correct` parameter set in the Vagrantfile.